# Mocha test "0 passing"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, testing, mocha.js, chai

I`m trying to write some tests for my react app.

I get this in console, when the tests are right.

```
0 passing (0ms)
```

Test file appTest.test.js

```
var expect = require('chai').expect
    , foo = 'bar'
    , beverages = { tea: [ 'chai', 'matcha', 'oolong' ] };

expect(foo).to.be.a('string');
expect(foo).to.equal('bar');
expect(foo).to.have.lengthOf(3);
expect(beverages).to.have.property('tea').with.lengthOf(3);
```

package.json

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --require @babel/register --require ./test/*.test.js   --watch",
```

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DstnI.png)

What is interesting, that if I put the wrong expectation it fails so it receives  the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `describe` and `it` functions provided by mocha to declare your tests. Read the [documentation](https://mochajs.org/#getting-started) of mocha for instructions on how to use it.

```
describe('My test', function() {
  it('foo should be "bar"', function(done) {
    expect(foo).to.be.a('string');
    expect(foo).to.equal('bar');
    expect(foo).to.have.lengthOf(3);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears `describe()` and `it()` need to not be wrapped into anything else, if they are wrapped mocha will not detect them.

`it()` can only be wrapped in `describe()` and `describe()` may only be wrapped in another `describe()`.

Even if there is an accepted answer, this fact should be emphasized appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I think the issue was that is that I tried to add async on the describe function like this:

```
describe("check1", async function() {
    let some_action = await my_action();
    it("do something", async function() {
         :
    });
});
```

After I changed to

```
describe("check1", function() {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await my_action();
    });

    it("do something", async function() {
         :
    });
});
```

It started working